# How can I access the redirected url in postman?

Tags: redirect, postman, web-api-testing

I'm sending a request on postman which is redirected upon completion. I can see the redirected url in Postman console. But I can't access it from the test tab.

How can one access the redirected url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off redirects on a specific request (toggle Automatically follow redirects):

[image: Disable request redirects]

Then you can access the Location header contents through:
`pm.response.headers.get('Location')`

Following that, you can hit the redirect URL via [sendRequest](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#pmsendrequest) or saving the URL in a Postman [variable](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/) and using [setNextRequest](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/).